# neural network training algorithms

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, training

When I first read about neural networks, I learned that Backpropagation is the algorithm used to train the neural network. I am interested if there are other alternatives (or better?) to BP.

What are the other training algorithms used in NN? And is BP is the best one, and that's why almost everyone uses it for training the NN model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, some alternatives are [feedback-alignment (FA)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0247v1), [Direct Feedback Alignment (DFA)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01596) and Indirect Feedback Alignment (IFA).

Comment: Thank you, I will look into those, why BP has such a good reputation in comparison with these alternatives?

Comment: Because it dates back to 70s, is quite simple and works great!

Comment: Thank very much. One last question if you may, is the code of these alternatives algorithms available? Meaning do you know of libraries that may has these code, like weka or toolbox in matlab?